# Java swing- perform an action on click

Tags: java, swing

I think I've coded myself into a bit of a corner here.  I am trying to do something to this effect using java swing.

On click of the button next, load a new line from a file (via line index number), then if the date from the line in the file has not yet arrived, grey out the next button.  My issue is that when I have the following code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter week number");
    int j = input.nextInt();
    String[] strArray = new String[4];        
    xmlLoader(j, strArray);

    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
    nextButton.setBounds(750, 250, 80, 30);
    nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
           j++;
           doNext(j, nextButton);
       } 
    });
```

I cannot pass the j because it's not final, and I can't change anything on the button if it's final, helpppp!

Specific error: local variable j is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: `nextButton.setBounds(750, 250, 80, 30);`  Don't do that.  It is very fragile.  Use layouts and (if necessary) sizes based upon the preferred size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may define `j` as a field in outer class.

```
class Sample{
   private int j;

   void method() {
     ...
     nextButton.setBounds(750, 250, 80, 30);
     nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
           j++;
           doNext(j, nextButton);
       }
      });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make the j class field instead of declaring local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Declare you j variable as : final Integer j = new Integer(0).
You will be able to change the value that the Integer class is wrapping.