# How to run method in the JFrame by clicking button in JDialog?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have a `JFrame` (called `FTask`) with public void method. Example code:

```
public void clear() {
    jTable1.clearSelection();
    jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    jButton3.setEnabled(false);
    jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    jTextArea1.setText(null);
}
```

Then, I have `JDialog` with a button. I want when I click the button, frame do the 'clear' method to the frame.

I've tried:

```
FTask ft = new FTask();
ft.clear();
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: *it didn't work* - how? What happened? Was there an error?

Comment: @Idos nothing has changed when I click the button.. :(

Comment: Well that is because your code is not being run when the button is clicked. You might want to look at adding some listeners and then add your code inside one. ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014704/java-swing-perform-an-action-on-click )

Comment: _Where_ have you put this piece of code?

Comment: @exilit in the button (jbutton), because i want when i press the button, the 'clear' method running in the jframe.

Comment: as i understand the call is happening inside the dialog, so you need to pass the JFrame instance to the dialog, so it can call `clear()`, while creating new instance from `FTask` and calling `clear()` will NOT affect the current instance. maybe if you show the JDialog code more help can be provided

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried:

```
    FTask ft = new FTask();
    ft.clear();
```

> But it didn't work.

No, it wouldn't. This code is creating a new (2nd instance) of the frame that is not set visible. What you need is a reference to the ***original frame.***

This can be fixed in a number of ways, too broad to go into here, and is Object Oriented Programming 101 that should be mastered before trying to write GUI'd apps. - which add their own complications.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use actionlistener in order to run the code when the button is clicked.

```
 JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
    //Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            //Execute when button is pressed

            if(e.getSource() == button){
                System.out.println("You clicked the button");

                //In your case:
                ft.clear();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you show me the way? i've tried this code, and hasn't worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "it hasn't worked" ? What did it do? Was there an error? If so, what error?

Comment: @FredK when i click the button, the 'clear()' method can not be executed.

Comment: How did you use the code? Did you just copy and paste it? You have to fit it in to your application. Or maybe you are using the clear method the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

As @Menno said, you have to use `ActionListener` in order to detect Button Clicks

Here is the Java 8 Style:

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Click me");

    //Add action listener to button
    button.addActionListener(
        ae -> ft.clear();
    );

    // Add button to frame
    add(button);
```